# How to refresh andoid photo gallery in unity

Tags: unity, c#

After saving a screenshot into the folder i cannot view the screenshot in the android gallery but can see the screenshot in the folder created.Is there anyway i can see it through gallery?

Comment: Could you provide some context into how you are generating the screenshot and where it is being stored?